# Is it possible to store SQL database in Glassfish Server?

Tags: web-services, glassfish

Currently, I'm working with a web-service which runs in the Glassfish server but I've been using my localhost/phpmyadmin/ to store the databases. Is it possible to store the database in the Glassfish server itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Use Java JDBC pool and create a connection then add the local database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can store the databases in the glassfish server it self in the admin console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever RDBMS database you want as long as you provide the jdbc driver for the connection to glassfish server
You should put the jdbc driver in the glassfish domains
and create a jdbc pool for it

In addition , for sql server you should enable tcp port ( by default : 1433)